# Google Maps Platform rejected your request. Invalid 'pb' parameter

Tags: android, google-maps, android-webview, google-maps-embed

I am trying to show Google map in webview, but it is saying

> Google Maps Platform rejected your request. Invalid request. Invalid 'pb' parameter.

But when I am rendering the same iframe on web browser, it is working perfectly

here is what I am trying to render in webview, this is the string stored in variable **iframeData**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d14988.154038971099!2d57.510438!3d-20.090677!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xc479c0ed4774c8e7!2sThe+Westin+Turtle+Bay+Resort+%26+Spa%2C+Mauritius!5e0!3m2!1sen!2smu!4v1513055435928" width="340.0" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my Android code to render this iframe into webview

```
String iframeData = //look above

WebView webViewMap = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webViewMap);
WebSettings settings = webViewMap.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setSupportZoom(false);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
}
settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
webViewMap.loadData(iframeData, "text/html", null);
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The URL doesn't look like a Google Maps Embed API URL. How did you create this URL? Is it copied from the share option of web interface?

Comment: I have a magento website, there this iframe is embeded and the map is showing, this same iframe data is sent in API and I am trying to render it in `WebView`. For other prdocuts it is working fine, but for this particular iframe it is not showing in Android

Comment: I got my `iframe` link from the "share/embed" item In my case, The name of the location I was trying to pin had an apostrophe in it and it was encoded in the URL as &#39; which threw the error. Removing that fixed the error and seems to have not affected the name when you click the pin,.

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge, yeah there were extra characters when I copied from google. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

The URL inside `iframe` in your example looks like a link obtained from share location on Google Maps web site. Typically this URL shouldn't be treated as Google Maps Platform product. However, for some reason Google treats it as Google Maps Platform in the `WebView` component.

I think this is a bug on Google side.

The workaround is replacing URL for share with URL from [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start). In this case you will have correct Google Maps Platform link and it should work as expected. Note that you will need a valid API key in order to use Google Maps Embed API.

The code snippet is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
      <iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=The+Westin+Turtle+Bay+Resort+%26+Spa%2C+Mauritius&key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

You should replace my API key with yours.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, And yes using Embed API like you mention worked, but the embed data that i mentioned is working fine on Website and IOS, it is just not working for Android and that too only this case all the other embedded map like mine are rendering, do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: In my opinion this is a bug on Google side. You should report it in the Google [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188814&template=788211).

Answer (score 2):

A seamless approach to this would be:

1. Search for the place you want to include on your iframe on [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/)
2. Click on the share button[image: share button]
3. When the modal opens, click on the Embed a map tab [image: copy html button]
4. Copy the HTML code of the map size you're after, and paste it inside your iframe.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar challenge in React JS but was able to find an effective solution.

**Solution**:

To create a dynamic Google Map in React, you can use the useEffect hook to update the src attribute of an iframe element with the URL containing the latitude and longitude values passed as props. Here's how you can implement it:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function GoogleMap({ lat, lon }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const iframeData = document.getElementById("iframeId");
    iframeData.src = `https://maps.google.com/maps?q=${lat},${lon}&hl=es;&output=embed`;
  }, [lat, lon]);

  return (
    <div>
      <iframe id="iframeId" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GoogleMap;
```

In this code, the ***useEffect*** hook is used to update the ***src*** attribute of the ***iframe*** element with the URL that includes the latitude and longitude values passed as props. The ***useEffect*** hook has ***lat*** and ***lon*** as dependencies, which means that the effect will run every time these values change.

To use this component in your React app, you can import it and pass the lat and lon values as props like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import GoogleMap from "./GoogleMap";

function App() {
  const lat = 37.7749;
  const lon = -122.4194;

  return (
    <div>
      <GoogleMap lat={lat} lon={lon} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In this example, the ***lat*** and ***lon*** values are hardcoded, but you can pass them dynamically from other parts of your app or from an API response, for example.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Original Issue:
When trying to embed a Google Maps location for "Hotel Yak & Yeti" using an iframe, the "pb" parameter in the embedded URL caused an error. The special character "&" in the hotel name was likely the cause of the issue.

Solution:
To resolve the problem, I removed the special characters from the hotel name, resulting in "Hotel Yak Yeti." Then, I edited the "pb" parameter in the URL accordingly. This adjustment ensures that the URL is properly encoded and validated.

Original Google Embedded URL:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d14128.750188412732!2d85.3197981!3d27.7114951!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x39eb19042204f6a1%3A0xa7af95e7f7d75e66!2sHotel%20Yak%20%26%20Yeti!5e0!3m2!1sen!2snp!4v1690259560583!5m2!1sen!2snp" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
```

Updated Embed URL:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3532.187395792953!2d85.31518467397605!3d27.711499772684373!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x39eb19042204f6a1%3A0xa7af95e7f7d75e66!2sHotel%20Yak%20Yeti!5e0!3m2!1sen!2snp!4v1689753786090!5m2!1sen!2snp" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
```

When saving this updated URL to the database, I used "Hotel%20Yak%20Yeti" to ensure proper URL encoding for the hotel name. This way, the embedded Google Maps location for "Hotel Yak Yeti" works seamlessly on my website.

Answer (score -2):

CORRECT ANSWER:

Encode the URL using URLEncoder.encode(...) to escape the characters & solve the issue.

```
String googleMapLink = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d14988.154038971099!2d57.510438!3d-20.090677!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xc479c0ed4774c8e7!2sThe+Westin+Turtle+Bay+Resort+%26+Spa%2C+Mauritius!5e0!3m2!1sen!2smu!4v1513055435928";
String encodedUrl = null;
try {
    encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(googleMapLink,"UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String iframe = "<iframe src=\""+ encodedUrl +"\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

googlemap_webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
googlemap_webView.loadData(iframe, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Hi @L-X, did you find a final solution for this embedded link problem. After several hours of debugging and checking every character in the links I tried encoding and it worked, maybe it can help you.